# Android Action Button not shown in action bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I want to display an icon on the action bar. But it always comes in the overflow list. Could you please help me up with a solution. This is my code.

**CreateScheduleActivity.java**

```
package com.mpeers.ui;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

    public class CreateScheduleActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_schedule);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
        return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
     }
```

**action_bar.xml in menu folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/plusicon"
          android:title="CS"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />


</menu>
```

Comment: try this `app:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: i changed it to always but no change

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the appcompat support library, you need to define

*xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"*

in the parent tag and then use **app:showAsAction** for controlling the visibility of the action items.

If you are not using the appcompat support library, you can use the **android:showAsAction** tag for controlling the visibility of the action items.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to replace app:showAsAction by android:showAsAction if you're not using the support library. This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

define `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in parent tag.

then use  `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Following is the example code.

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.taazi.android.MainActivity" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
            android:title="@string/action_search"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_right_drawer"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_play_over_video"
            android:title="@string/action_right_drawer"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    </menu>
```

Comment: Which theme are you using? appcompat?

Comment: Try replacing whole action_bar.xml code with above code.